# Add markers to google maps based on form info

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was wondering if anyone knew of a tutorial or how to use a form to add markers to a google map. I want a person to be able to select some things from a form and click submit and have it refresh the map with the markers on it. I assume the map will have to be in an iframe or something, but I am not sure how to do the markers like that. Anything will help

Comment: Well there's a [demo of how to add markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers) on the reference documentation.  How you do it with your form *really* depends on what your form contains.

Comment: So where would the marker go, centre of current view? [Incidentally, when you respond to a comment, make sure you prefix it, or include, the name of the person who you are addressing, prefixed with an at symbol.  Otherwise they are not notified of the comment, unless they are the question asker, or the answerer.]

Comment: First step is to read the tutorial and developers guide, start here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you **don't need a refresh** to add markers on the map.With javascript api you can add markers on the fly to the map.Now **if you also want these locations to be stored in a database** than you should probably make a form,although an ajax request will be just fine.So as orbling mentioned start by reading the documentation.

Nevertheless i will give a simple scenario and actions to solve it.

1. Make a database in lets say mysql to store your points.
2. [Create a page with a map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)
3. Create some textfields and some button on that same page to trigger some actions like [adding markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)
4. On some events send ajax requests to the server to store your location.

These actions can be implemented let's say with php+mysql or jsp+postgis or any combination you like.

Comment: all the links got 404